# Firebase Firestore: create collection in collection

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

How to create a collection in collection like this:

```js
    firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection("account").doc('doc-account').set({...});
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is about how to create a **subcollection** named `account` under a root collection named `users`.

You just need to do exactly the way you have shown in your question, using the `set()` method on the `doc-account` [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference): as soon a first document will be added under the `account` subcollection, this subcollection will exist.

Same effect if you use the `add()` method on the `account` subcollection, as follows:

```
firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection("account").add({...});
```

---

And you even don't need to have a `users` collection, i.e. having a document in the `users` collection. This last point is a bit surprising at first sight, let's explain it with an example:

Take a `doc1` document under the `col1` collection

```
col1/doc1/
```

and another one `subDoc1` under the `subCol1` (sub-)collection

```
col1/doc1/subCol1/subDoc1
```

Actually, from a technical perspective, these two documents are not at all relating to each other. They just **share a part of their path** but nothing else. This is why the `subDoc1` document (and its parent `subCol1` collection) can exist without the `doc1` existing. One notable side effect of this is that if you delete a document, its sub-collection(s) still exist.

Comment: I tried this. But when I try to set a subcollection, I have this error `[Error: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.]`. But without setting a subcollection, my requests works... I don't understand why...

Comment: This is because your Firestore security rules do not allow the creation of docs in the subcollection. You should review the rules and allow this operation. If the adaptation does not work, you can update your question with your security rules, I will review them.