# in firebase firestore how can I update a document without overwriting subcollections?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I update a document in Firebase Firestore without overwriting subcollections ?

Specifically in Flutter.

Comment: can you explain what exactly you want?

Comment: Same as document without subcollections. You have an answer relevant to your question level.

Comment: I have a collection of 'users' and within it there are documents of users with metadata field and a subcollection called 'shares', the data inside them change periodically and i want to update the the fields only without overwriting the whole document.

Comment: Edit your question if you have more information about the question, not paste it in comments.

Comment: @Mises no not same in flutter it overrides feilds

Comment: Actually, from a technical perspective, a parent and a child collections are not at all relating to each other. More details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69257154/3371862).

Answer (score 1):

Update a document won't overwrite your subcollection.

Comment: Thanks just found out a min ago, tho it's weird that it overwrites fields but not subcollections.

Answer (score 1):

Just set your documents fields directly:

```
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
          .doc(DOCUMENT_ID)
          .set({ "FIELD_NAME": "FIELD_VALUE" });
```

This will not affect the document collections.

If you want to just update some fields without affect other fields, you can use update method:

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
          .doc(DOCUMENT_ID)
          .update({ "FIELD_NAME": "FIELD_VALUE" });
```

For further information:

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/